# Why does Stanley Ipkiss go bald when he becomes The Mask?

Tags: the-mask

In *The Mask*, when Stanley Ipkiss puts on the mask and becomes the Mask, he not only gets more bold but also goes completely bald. However, neither Milo nor Dorian, who both put on the mask as well, lose their hair.

**So why does Stanley Ipkiss go bald when he becomes the Mask?**

Comment: When Stanley becomes the Mask, he essentially becomes a cartoon character.  And realistic hair is hard to animate, so he is bald.  Remember, his Mask persona is based off of old Loony Toons - most of the human characters (who didn't always wear hats) were bald.  You were either furry (with the fur drawn mostly as skin), feathered (likewise), bald, and/or wore a hat.

Answer (score 10):

The [film script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Mask,-The.html) strongly implies that because Stanley has so little personality of his own, that when he's imprinted by Loki's mask the *extent* of his transformation is near-complete. This evidently includes both his mental **and physical** appearance.

By comparison, both Dorian and Milo put their own stamp on the mask-transformation through their strong-willed personalities, only changing partially.

> THE MASK CREATURE
>
> He's dressed in a snazzy zoot suit - a distortion of the paisley
>   material of Stanley's pajamas.
>               **The head is no longer Stanley's. It's large, bald and bright green. The huge bug-eyes glow with mischief. The nose is small,
>   bony and beaked. The mouth and teeth are enormous and gleaming white
>   as he breaks into a leering grin.**
>               The overall effect is devilishly loony, but not altogether unhuman. In fact, there's something downright charming about him.
>               The Mask checks himself out in the mirror and likes what he sees.

as compared with

> With a CRACK of thunder a whirlwind of light and power swirls around
>   Dorian's figure. Unlike Stanley's transformation, Dorian's is much
>   more diabolical. He grows and changes within a nimbus of ROARING 
>   light. Finally the light dies away and Dorian/Mask rises from a 
>   circle of swirling smoke.
>             **While Stanley was a zoot suited bee-bopper in hyper-drive,  Dorian/Mask is more like a hulking evil GENIE, fresh out of the lamp
>   and pissed at the world. His diamond earring and touches of his
>   neuvo-gangster look is still apparent,** but his huge grin stretches out
>   like a TYRANNOSAURUS Rex's under eyes that glow green with wicked
>   power. His voice is a deep inhuman RUMBLE.

Comment: Well, if I recall correctly, the mask brings out the inner personality of its wearer. Stanley becomes the womaniser he wants to be. We see him later integrating some aspects into his outer personality, for instance when telling off his boss. Dorian just becomes more of the villain he already is. But that doesn't really explain why Stanley goes bald. Loki isn't bald, either.

Comment: @SQB - It certainly grants Stanley his wishes and he seems to gain some measure of control as the film progresses.

Comment: Does this mean the lead character is more strong willed in Son of the Mask as he doesn't lose his hair either?

Comment: @User13267 - The sequels seem to be in a different continuity, hence the "rules" seem to be different also.